# Chaincode Endorsement policy in YAML file

Tags: yaml, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger

I am studying **Hyperledger Fabric** blockchain framework ,trying out sample codes . i ran the **BYFN** network from the tutorial given in the Fabric docs(Fabric samples release 1.0) .
Chaincode endorsement policy rules are given in 
http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/endorsement-policies.html#specifying-endorsement-policies-for-a-chaincode

I want to know the equivalent **YAML** format policy for :
"AND('Org1.member', 'Org2.member')"

That is i want one member from both org1 and org2 to sign the query proposal for response . I want the policy in .**yaml** format

**OR IS IT DEFINED ONLY ON INSTANTIATION OF CHAINCODE.**

If it is defined during instantiation then will it apply to other requests as well(transactionProposal,queryproposal) ?

Thanks

Comment: Note that the 'latest' documentation is published from the most recent release branch. Hence, the documentation you are reviewing is not (necessarily) consistent with that for 1.0 (the samples you are working with).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Fabric, chaincode deployment is independent of channel creation, and the endorsement policy is specified with either the CLI `peer chaincode deploy` command or the corresponding SDK method. Hence there is no yaml equivalent presently.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a sample .yaml file if you want in the

> hyperledger-fabric-java-sdk

from the source: 
https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-java.

You can find the file in the following directory:

> src/test/fixture/sdkintegration/chaincodeendorsementpolicy.yaml

Feel free to comment if you understand anything from the structure of the file.